# Displaying path instead of product image in my account page

Tags: magento-1.9

i am trying to display product images in My account page. but its displaying as below , means instead of image, its displaying below path :

**http://sitename.com/media/catalog/product/**

I tried

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage() );
```

**related code** :

```
<?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product) {

echo $product->getName().' <br>';
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product>getImage() ); 
?>
```

**complete code** :http://pastebin.com/rfGTE38h

we are saving product details in one more custom table , is the image is trying to fetch from there ?

[image]

**Edit**

when i tried below code , i am getting full path of image, but i want to display image :

**sitename.com/media/catalog/product/1/8/183615421.png**

`echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config') ->getMediaUrl( $product->getThumbnail() )`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(350 ,350)->setQuality(100); ?>
<img class="name_class_here" src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>" />
```

Comment: i tried like `$imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
    $imageCacheUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(135,135);
 echo $imageCacheUrl;` now its displaying different url instead of image : `sitename.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/135x135/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/place`

Comment: please check `edit` part in question

Comment: Look my edit now

Comment: thanks , its working now, i need to display small size without losing quality, when i used `<img width="100" height="100" src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>" />` looks like its destroying quality of image. can you please guide me how i can resize without losing quality of image ?

Comment: Please look my answer now.

Comment: before it was displaying like this : http://prnt.sc/eoyu9x , now its displaying like this : http://prnt.sc/eoyw4l , means seems image size is reduced, but image disappears.....

Comment: In a backend, you have selected the image for these three: Base Image , Small Image , Thumbnail or they are not empty ?

Comment: yes, i selected for `base , small, thumbinal` for that one image.....

Comment: Recheck your code well and do it as my answer, in my side it works fine, otherwise I think you have a problem in your responsive which disappears the image after some size.

Comment: sure, let me check some more time.....

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time...... you are the real prince of magento.....

Comment: You are welcome ;)